# IntelliJ Editor Color rules not applied, I see everything in white

Tags: intellij-idea

I have this weird problem in IntelliJ. I made a screen capture:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImJ4QboLmwM

What happens is, the color profile I picked is applied for about 2 seconds, as I type (or copy / paste..) and then by some magic everything is back to all white.

I think this is caused by some sort of cache problem or bug in IntelliJ. Any help?

Also, in "Show Differences View" the older version will be highlighted correctly:

[image]

Comment: We're not quite sure. Could you submit a ticket to [JetBrains Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us) with your `idea.log` attached (*Help | Show log*), and we'll investigate further? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I do not know how to submit a ticket, but here is a .log after I reproduced the problem: http://pastebin.com/4GXsCYCJ

Comment: @breandan could you please see my comment above?

Comment: I submitted [a ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152563) for you, you can add a Star (★) for updates. Thanks for the detailed bug report!